# Why does ggplot change the position of the parameter values of data= and mapping= when using "pipe" operator?

Tags: r, ggplot2, operators

hearted people who clicked in to see this question.I just started learning to use ggplot.

```
ggplot(mpg)
aes(x = displ) |> 
  ggplot(mpg)
```

[image: image src]

The first command `mpg` is passed to `ggplot` as an argument to `data =`, while the second command is of the same form, but why `mpg` is passed as an argument to `mapping =` instead of the incoming aes function as an argument to `mapping =`?

The error goes like this:

[image: img]

It looks like `mpg` is being pushed to the side. What is the logic here?

Thank you for your patience.

I try to search on google and asked my friends. But I can't get an answer. Have I made some mistakes or is this some kind of feature of the R language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipe passes its left hand side to the first unnamed argument of the right hand side. So `aes(x = displ) |> ggplot(mpg)` is equivalent to `ggplot(aes(x = displ), mpg)`, which in turn is equivalent to `ggplot(data = aes(x = displ), mapping = mpg)` since that’s the order of `ggplot()`’s arguments.

If you want to get around this, you can explicitly pass `mpg` to the `data` arg:

```
aes(x = displ) |> 
  ggplot(data = mpg)
```

or explicitly pass your `aes()` call to `mapping` using the pipe placeholder (`_`):

```
aes(x = displ) |> 
  ggplot(mpg, mapping = _)
```